# TypeScript Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'FileList'

Tags: typescript, filelist

I enable users to upload multiple files. Then I need to iterate over these files and perform some actions. I wanted to add some extra functionality to `FileList` but TS does not know `forEach` on `FileList` arrays. This is my code:

```
public uploadMultiple(evt){
    console.log(evt.files);
    FileList.prototype.forEach = function(callback) {[].forEach.call(this, callback)};
}
```

Comment: `.forEach` is a property of native javascript Array.prototype.
In Typescript, if you want to add functionality to the FileList class, you do it in the FileList class declaration... favoring classical inheritance over prototypal.

Comment: @Rob_M not true, you can usually augment existing declarations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare the extra functions on the `FileList` interface before you can assign it. You can do this using declaration merging. If you are using a module system the merged interface need to be declared in `global`:

```
declare global {
    interface FileList {
        forEach(callback: (f: File) => void) : void;
    }
}
FileList.prototype.forEach = function(callback) {  ... };
```

Answer (score 9):

`FileList` is not to be confused with array. The list is a iterator with other properties like `length` and `item`.

A possible solution would be to use a for-loop, which is in my opinion the best way to do it.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
    const file = files[i];
    ...
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Answer (score 0):

```
imagList: Array<any> = [];

uploadMultiple(event) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        this.imagList.pop();
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
                this.imagList[i] = event.target.files[i];
            }
            var formData = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < this.imagList.length; i++) {
            formData.append("File", <string>this.imagList[i]);
        }
        }
    }
```

You can try this it is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
(target.files as unknown as File[]).forEach((newFile) => {
    // do something
});
```

I can also recommend this solution. It's an easy one liner. Keep it simple stupid. But choose whatever solution you like.

Comment: Why do you prefer this articulation over the accepted answer—or either of the other previous answers for that matter? Why should future readers consider using this instead? Is it better suited for particular scenarios? Does it use newer syntax that offers some benefit? Please explain.

Comment: Shhhhhhh shhh shhh

Comment: I’m not following. Can you please expand on your answer?

Comment: You should maybe focus on your important problems, rather than raging around here but sure. I had the same problem and this solution here didn't fit. So I added the solution I ended up with. It's always good to have several solutions to choose from.

Comment: @JeremyCaney What? Nothing like: "Yes ok you are right. Sorry that I got angry. I maybe had a bad day. Wish you the best."

Comment: I just reread my comment and it doesn’t seem angry to me. It certainly wasn’t intended as such. My goal is to prompt contributors to improve their answers in order to better aid future readers. If you feel my comment is rude, feel free to flag it as such. If you think reviewers shouldn't leave feedback like this, I’d encourage you to take that issue up on Meta Stack Overflow. I do wish you the best, regardless. I also wish you’d invest this time into editing your answer to address my feedback; that would make it more useful, and more likely to build your reputation around here.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Done. Enough? If not, what else would you recommend. I am not looking for reputation. Just wanted to help. btw

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(files, file => {
  console.log(file);
})
```